# Saving SVG in Rails Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails application where I am storing image in the model using

```
has_one_attached: logo
```

However, when I check in the AWS console, I see that the file is saved as a text file with the contents of SVG in it. When I try to retrieve the image using a signed URL, it gives me back the content of the text file.

I want to display this image in my HTML. How can I render this SVG in my application?

Answer (score 0):

because svg is text ,it will be saved as text.

for displaying it in rails app [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36992492/10385358) should work