# Rails: Add SVG images to rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg

I have an HTML website which I am currently converting to Rails erb views.

It contains an SVG image called `sprite.svg` that contains all the icons for the websites.

For example an icon for **search** is represented this way:

```
<svg width="20px" height="20px">
  <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#search-20"></use>
</svg>
```

And an icon for **cross** is represented this way:

```
<svg width="20px" height="20px">
  <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#cross-20"></use>
</svg>
```

I am trying to import this to a rails erb views like this:

First, I added the `sprite.svg` image to the project this way `app/assets/images/sprite.svg`

And then I referenced it this way:

```
<svg width="20px" height="20px">
  <%= image_tag('sprite#search-20') %>
</svg>
```

but the icon doesn't seem to show up.

Can someone help me to figure out a better way to represent this in order for all the SVG icons in the svg image to show in the rails application views. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the image_tag to display the svgs in the view. In order to show them up you can either use render or a helper method to "translate" the svg and then call it in your view.

This should help: [How do I display SVG image in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986925/how-do-i-display-svg-image-in-rails)