# How to display icon from svg sprite in pseudo element with ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, svg, sass, sprite

I want to create a menu like this `Home >` where the right arrow is an icon in an svg sprite. I would like to place the `>` as a psuedo element in the css selector so that i can make any menu have the right arrow just by adding the css selector `.menu-arrow`. I am trying to do this in ruby on rails 6 with no success.

I have tried adding the svg icon sprite as a background content but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

My svg sprite

```
path to svg sprite: app/assets/images/sprites.svg


<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="icon-check-solid" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M10.869 27.463l-10.4-10.4c-0.625-0.625-0.625-1.638 0-2.263l2.263-2.263c0.625-0.625 1.638-0.625 2.263 0l7.006 7.006 15.006-15.006c0.625-0.625 1.638-0.625 2.263 0l2.263 2.263c0.625 0.625 0.625 1.638 0 2.263l-18.4 18.4c-0.625 0.625-1.638 0.625-2.263-0z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-chevron-down-solid" viewBox="0 0 28 32">
<path d="M12.939 23.842l-12.146-12.146c-0.586-0.586-0.586-1.536 0-2.121l1.417-1.417c0.585-0.585 1.533-0.586 2.119-0.002l9.672 9.626 9.672-9.626c0.586-0.583 1.534-0.582 2.119 0.002l1.417 1.417c0.586 0.586 0.586 1.536 0 2.121l-12.146 12.146c-0.586 0.586-1.536 0.586-2.121 0z"></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>`
```

My css class

```
.menu-arrow {
      &::after {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 2rem;
        width: 2rem;
        background-image: asset-url("images/sprites.svg#icon-chevron-down-solid");
        transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5);
        fill: var(--color-white);
        color: var(--color-white);
        font-weight: 700;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    }
}
```

How do i make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/) suggests the #id  in the CSS url is referencing a `view` rather than a `symbol`

You can certainly use your sprite as an inline SVG (shadow) DOM element via `use`, and make a helper to streamline the process ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986925/how-do-i-display-svg-image-in-rails/68569598#68569598))

For your chevron specifically, you can achieve an almost identical graphic element using your pseudo element without a background (borders on two sides with rounded corners and rotated 45deg). I made a pen [here](https://codepen.io/scootman/pen/ebmrOm) that demonstrates this approach